# Using .in files with Java programs

Tags: java, file-io

I have had advice from other sources on the interwebs that I should do the following for a .txt file. What I want to do is use a .in file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadTextFile
{
  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException 
  {
    File inFile = new File ("input.txt");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (inFile);
    while (sc.hasNextLine())
    {
      String line = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println (line);
    }
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

I have also had this advice from the interwebz but there is an error in my compiler which does not allow my files address to parse as a string. (citing errors such as "invalid escape characters")

```
File file = new File(**"F:\\A-small-practice.in"**);
    File outFile = new File("F:\\A-small-practice.out");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
    int testCases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    for(int t=1;t<=testCases;t++){
        /*
         * Your code here
         */

        bw.write("Case #" + t +": Yes I did it\n");
    }
    br.close();
    bw.close();
```

What do you recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as `input.in` exists as a file, you can read it by simply changing

```
File inFile = new File ("input.txt");
```

to

```
File inFile = new File ("input.in");
```

This works as long as `input.in` was created as a text file, either originally or converted from a .txt file.

Comment: But the file has to be inside my project folder in eclipse correct?

Comment: Correct. So if your project is in `C:\Users\$you\$workspace\$project` then your file should be saved in `C:\Users\$you\$workspace\$project\input.in`

Comment: Tried that earlier. Didn't work but I'm sure someone else has the answer.